# 2D array with four infinite directions

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to create a 2D map of tiles. Example:

```
Cell[,] cells;

for(int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    {
        cells[x, y] = new Cell();
    }
}
```

The first cell would be at (0|0). What if I want to have this cell as my center and create new cells on the left and top side? These cells would have negative indices.

One way to fix this would be a value that determines the maximum length of one direction. Having a map of 100 tiles per side would place the center of the map at (50|50).

Let's say there would be no hardware limitations and no maximum length per side, what is the best way to create a 2D map with a (0|0) center? I can't image a better way than accessing a cell by its x and y coordinate in a 2D array.

Comment: “These cells would have negative indices”? That's not how arrays work in C#. You either need to not use arrays, or redefine your center to a positive value and use offsets (which can be negative) instead of indexes. Which is better? To know that we'd have to know how you're measuring “better”, and you haven't told us that.

Comment: You should have a class Cell with four properties that are : Cell left; Cell top; Cell right; Cell bottom.  You can always enumerate through the cells by going to adjacent cell.  The Cell class will also have Row and Column Number.  Now to make it easier to access the cells you can have static List<List<Cell>> map which will contain mostly null cells except for the center row and center column.

Comment: Will you **only** be access these objects by index (x,y coords)?  Or will you want to reference them by other means as well?

Answer (score 4):

Well, Arrays are logical constructs, not physical ones.
This means that the way we look at the the `0,0` as the `top left corner`, while might help visualize the content of a 2-D array (and in fact, a 2-D array is also somewhat of a visualization aid), is not accurate at all - the `0,0` "cell" is not a corner, and indexes are not coordinates, though it really helps to understand them when you think about them like they are.

That being said, there is nothing stopping you from creating your own class, that implement an indexer that can take both positive and negative values - in fact, according to [Indexers (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) -

> Indexers do not have to be indexed by an integer value; it is up to you how to define the specific look-up mechanism.

Since you are not even obligated to use integers, you most certainly can use both positive and negative values as your indexer.

I was testing an idea to use a list of lists for storage and dynamically calculate the storage index based on the class indexer, but it's getting too late here and I guess I'm too tired to do it right. It's kinda like the solution on the other answer but I was attempting to do it without making you set the final size in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can't use negative indices in an array or list, they're just not the right structure for a problem like this... You could, however, write your own class that handles something like this.

Simply pass in the size of the grid into the constructor, and then use the index operator to return a value based off of an an adjusted index... Something like this... Wrote it up really fast, so it probably isn't ideal in terms of optimization.

```
public class Grid<T> {
        T[,] grid { get; }

        int adjustment { get; }

        int FindIndex(int provided) {
            return provided + adjustment;
        }

        public Grid(int dimension) {
            if (dimension <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Grid dimension cannot be <= 0");
            if (dimension % 2 != 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Grid must be evenly divisible");
            adjustment = dimension / 2;
            grid = new T[dimension, dimension];
        }

        public T this[int key, int key2] {
            get {
                return grid[FindIndex(key), FindIndex(key2)];
            }
            set {
                grid[FindIndex(key), FindIndex(key2)] = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

I used these to test it:

```
        var grid = new Grid<int>(100);
        grid[-50, -50] = 5;
        grid[0, 1] = 10;
```

You can just switch it to:

```
        var grid = new Grid<Cell>(100);
```

This only works for a grid with equal dimensions... If you need separate dimensions, you'll need to adjust the constructor and the FindIndex method.

I think that an infinitely sized grid would be dangerous. If you increase the size to the right, you'd have to reposition the center.. Which means, what you think will be at 0,0 will now be shifted as the grid is no longer properly centered.

Additionally, performance of such a structure would be a nightmare as you cannot rely on an array to be infinite (as it inherently isn't). So you'd either have to continuously copy the array (like how a list works) or use a linked list.. If using a linked list, you would have to do enormous amounts of iteration to get whatever value you want.